# Template for Components in Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I am developing a Joomla component. They component has its own design and images that aren't relevant to the website. What should I do so that the component should have its own template?

Currently, the component output is displayed in a part of current template. Like the menus footer and header of the main template are displayed and then component data is added in a block. I want the component to control all the template, it should have its own footer header etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify tmpl parameter which will call only component.

You can try something like this-
http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_component&tmpl=component

This tmpl parameter calls the component.php of your current template.In the absence of this parameter it calls the site normally with all your modules.
I hope this will clear the working of this parameter.

Comment: will this still work if SEF is turned on? Just curious as I have never tried it before.

Comment: @Lodder:I have tried it many times but did not care about SEF.But I think it should work.

Comment: @Irfan This will add an extra parameter to query also there will be a chance of error if the parameter goes missing. Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: @backTangent:I have updated the answer let me know if this is not clear yet.